# Requesting Advice On Preventing Ransomware (also very odd text in my win.ini cfg)

Tags: windows-7, malware, ransomware

I had just recently prevented a ransomware attack and am still looking for malware as I am curious. I had looked in my `win.ini` file this morning and found some odd text that even Google Translate couldn't decipher.

I am also looking for advice on how to combat these issues further than using a antivirus or malware program.

[image: Screenshot of win.ini file]

Comment: Backup, backup, backup. So simple, but yet almost never done. That is how you protect your data.

Comment: Yes, something I definitely take for granted. Although this is a recreational computer and my data isn't something i'm upset about losing or wouldn't necessarily give a gain for anyone else. I'm more worried about my PC lasting for as long as I want it to haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running Windows 7. Windows only [uses a `win.ini` file in a very limited context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIN.INI), for 16-bit support. However, those `win.ini` files don't contain the content that yours does, so this one was almost definitely introduced by a third-party.

I tried typing the contents of the file into Google Translate myself and got this:

[image]

> Easy to clean up
>   Powered by Discuz!

Wikipedia says that [Discuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discuz!) is Chinese internet forum software, in which case we can assume Google mistakenly identified the language as Japanese, or this Chinese company actually is writing its Read Me files in Japanese.

If you've used Discuz or one of their products before on your machine, that would be an explanation for how this file got there, but even if you had, it's very suspect for any company to leave behind a file that looks like a Windows configuration file, and this alone could point to malicious motives. The software that left behind this `.ini` file could be the same one that tried to execute ransomware on your machine, or it could not. Either way, the forensics of the situation doesn't really matter much at this point.

You say you don't care about your data on this computer. If that's true, then the best way to proceed is to nuke it from orbit - that is, wipe it and start with a fresh install. Good malware can extricate itself deep into your system, and can make it difficult to next to impossible to truly undo the effects of. For this reason, in situations like yours where keeping old data isn't necessary, a fresh install of the operating system is a much quicker, less tedious solution than the painstaking work of (effectively) purging a system of all threats and then undoing the damage that those threats have wreaked.

You say you want to "combat" these issues "further than" using an antivirus, which I'll understand to mean that you've already run one or several, including at boot.

Beyond that, to make sure you're never in this situation again, it's about prevention. You do this by:

- Having a real-time (i.e on-access) antivirus installed and always running
- Making *regular* backups
- Regularly updating your operating system and programs
- Educating yourself on just how strongly hackers rely on social engineering, and then how to protect yourself from it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also thanks for the tips. The only problem is the text is wrongfully translated as when I typed it in, I got a completely different translation which was; "Do not worry, I will definitely do it. Mayu" plus the fact that that isn't Japanese I have ever seen and that the unidentified text is impossible to be translated into Hiragana (the characters under the current gibberish) unless this is some form of native Japanese that isn't traditional Chinese. This text was also spammed about 1000 times in the .ini and was located in system32. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DSBMitchy No problem. Bit of an update, I previously stated that Windows 7 doesn't use `win.ini` files - searching my own system, this isn't strictly true as it seems that it uses them for the very rare case of 16-bit support. Either way, a `win.ini` file that contains content like that is definitely rogue and should be gotten rid of.